# Find matrix that satisfies matrix equation

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-equations

I am trying to find a matrix $A$ that satisfies the following type of equation:

$$A^\dagger A = f(B,C,...)$$

where the right-hand side is a function of known matrices $B,C,...$

Is there a general approach for this?

EDIT: The matrices $B,C,\dots$ are fixed and independent, and the right-hand side does not depend on $A$.

Comment: This is at best vague. Are $B, C, ...$ fixed or do they depend on $A$? Ditto for $f$.

Comment: $\dagger$ is Hermitian transpose

Comment: Sorry but it is still very unclear what you mean. Are you fixing a function $f$ of matrix arguments and want to know what matrices can appear in the LHS for arbitrary $B$, $C,$ ... of some sort, or what else? Maybe you can try to spell out an example.

Comment: For example, find $A$ that satisfies $A^\dagger A = B+CD^\dagger+C^\dagger D$

Comment: Matrices are square, so say $n\times n$

Answer (score 1):

We have the following matrix equation in $\mathrm X \in \mathbb C^{n \times n}$

$$\mathrm X^* \mathrm X = \mathrm A$$

where $\mathrm A \in \mathbb C^{n \times n}$ is given. Since $\mathrm X^* \mathrm X$ is Hermitian and positive semidefinite, $\mathrm A$ must also be Hermitian and positive semidefinite. Hence, $\mathrm A$ is diagonalizable. Let its eigendecomposition be

$$\mathrm A = \mathrm V \Lambda \mathrm V^*$$

Thus, one solution to the matrix equation is

$$\bar{\mathrm X} := \Lambda^{\frac 12} \mathrm V^*$$